# How to make a space between left column and text in the middle

Tags: css

I have 2 columns (left and right), and these columns are vertical and have images and text and links.
I want to put text in the middle of the page, left column and right column but in the middle there is no column but when i paste the text i get aligning problem. but my text is touching the left column image or boarder, unless if i center the text witch i don't want to center it.

How can i make a space between the element on the left column and my text in the middle of the page so i can justify it properly?

```
<div style="position: relative; float: right; text-align: center;">
      <!-- Images in a vertical line here-->
</div>

<div style="position: relative; float: left; padding-right: 1px; text-align: center;">
      <!-- Images in a vertical line here-->
</div>
```

Thank you,

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You want text in between the 2 `<div>`s and align that in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `margin` would not help much, but You could put some container (another div) in those divs having `padding-right` and `padding-left`.

Comment: Margin didn't help at all. padding did mess my whole layout. this design goes into blog post html area directly. i can't use external css. only inline. and padding didn't work as margin.

Comment: Using padding-left made my text goes below the end of these side columns.

Comment: I fixed it, just resized the width of the image in the left column. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking to add `margin: *some distance in em, px, or %*` or `padding: *some distance in em, px, or %*` to your style rules, depending on where you want that space to occur relative to the CSS box.

Comment: How can i make that? i want the border of the box to give margin to the text as a space, as the text are is just blog post, no way to use style.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle to try and make what you've requested: http://jsfiddle.net/MEA8W/

**CSS:**

```
.column {
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 50%;
}

.column p {
    padding: 10px
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="column">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec vestibulum mi, eu mollis nibh. Vestibulum euismod, orci ut porttitor dictum, velit dolor sodales leo, at iaculis metus leo malesuada mi. In non fermentum nulla. Vivamus in dapibus dui. Nulla quis mi commodo, tincidunt eros gravida, rutrum nibh. Vestibulum ac arcu vulputate, tincidunt ante id, molestie massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <p>
        Quisque aliquam ultricies varius. Phasellus viverra congue massa, et fringilla sapien. Quisque quis tristique nisi, sit amet rhoncus nulla. Nulla bibendum mauris pretium dui faucibus rhoncus. Praesent nec mauris ac enim auctor rhoncus a ultrices nisl. Nulla commodo lorem vel eleifend semper. Etiam ac sapien iaculis lacus interdum sodales. Maecenas sed turpis sapien. Vestibulum faucibus ipsum vitae hendrerit egestas. Phasellus cursus congue tempus. Nulla facilisi. Donec vestibulum posuere est, ut fringilla nunc congue sit amet. Aenean et ultricies quam. 
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using inline css inside a post, i have 2 columns on both sides and the text in the middle, so it like 3 columns. you made the padding between the 2 columns. this is not what i want. i have text article in the middle of the page, and on the left a column and on the right a column, the text have no space with the left column. this is my problem.